# In chromium Edge, is there a way to disable the new tab page and use a blank page instead?

Tags: chromium, microsoft-edge, browser-tabs

When I open a new tab, I just want to see a blank page. For my home page, I've used the URL `data://text,`.  I just want a blank page with nothing on it.  When I go to customize the page, it takes me to the page and there appears to be no way in the UI to change it.  Hoping for a setting that can be updated manually.

Comment: New tab is somewhat limited. Open Chromium Edge Settings, "Start, Home, New Tabs". The new Tab page only has 2 settings:  Customize or Preload New Tab Page (which you do not want)

Comment: [Have you tried configuring the GPO policy?](https://d1ny9casiyy5u5.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/GPO-Edge-configuration.webp)